# Mode=TwoWay return Null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

After a lot of hours I finally found what is the problem that cause the bug. Before to show the code that present the problem I need to explain the situation.

**Binding and properties structure**

In my application there is a `ComboBox` that bind as `ItemSource` a list of `Rounds` and as `SelectedItem` the `Round` selected from the list by the user.

The `ComboBox` have this structure:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Rounds}" DisplayMemberPath="RoundName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRound, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

as you can see I've as modality `TwoWay` this allow me to update the property `SelectedRound` automatically when the user change the `Item` selected.

This is the class `Round`:

```
public class Round
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; } 
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string RoundName { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the properties used by the `ComboBox`:

```
//List of rounds available
private List<Round> _rounds;
public List<Round> Rounds
{
    get { return _rounds; }
    set
    {
        _rounds = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

//Selected round on ComboBox
private Round _selectedRound;
public Round SelectedRound
{
    get { return _selectedRound; }
    set
    {
        _selectedRound = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

both properties implement the `OnPropertyChanged()`.

**How the properties valorization works**

In the app there is a method called `LoadRounds()` that is called each time the user press a button, this method have the following instruction:

```
public void LoadRounds(Team team)
{    
     //Fill the source of ComboBox with the rounds of the new team
     Rounds = team.Rounds.ToList(); //<- Create a copy, so no reference

     //Get the selected round
     SelectedRound = Rounds?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == team.CurrentRound.Id);
}
```

the `SelectedRound` is taken from a `team` property called `CurrentRound`, in particular each `team` have a round, so for a practice example:

```
[Rounds id available in Rounds property]
37487
38406
38405
37488
37486
...

[CurrentRound id of team]
38405
```

so the `SelectedRound` will contain the `Round` with `Id` 38405, and the `linq` query working well.

**The problem**

I set a `breakpoint` on `_selectedRound = value;`, the first firing time the `value` is a `Round` item (38405), but there is also a second firing time (that shouldn't be) that have as value `null`.

After a lot of hours spended on pc to understand why this situation happen I figure out.

Seems that the `ComboBox` (the `TwoWay` mode) doesn't know how to map the `SelectedRound` from the `ItemSource`, so essentially:

```
1. [Item Source updated with new Rounds]
2. [SelectedRound updated from the new `Rounds` available]
3. [SelectedRound setter called again with a null value]
```

I used also the stack call window for see if there is any method that call the setter property another time, but there is no external method that call the setter, so I guess is the `TwoWay` mode that fire the setter again.

How can I fix this situation? I know that this post is a bit complicated, I'm available to answer to all questions, and for provided more details if needed.

Thanks to all, have a good day.

**UPDATE #1**

This is my `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

1. The method `LoadRounds` is called when the user change the selection on a `DataGrid`, the `DataGrid` contains all `teams`, so I get the `team` selected by the user on the `DataGrid`, and then call the method `LoadRounds`.
2. All the teams are contained in a `DataGrid`, the `ItemSource` is a `List<Team>`.
3. At the end of the method `LoadRounds` I save the current `Round` of the `Team` on a property called `SelectedRoundSaved`, simply doing:

   `SelectedRoundSaved = Clone(SelectedRound);`

in this way I prevent to reload the `Rounds` if the `SelectedRoundSaved` is equal to `SelectedRound`.

the `Clone` method allow me to clone the object, and have this structure:

```
 public T Clone<T>(T source)
 {
    if (ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source), deserializeSettings);
}
```

it use the `NewtonSoft.Json` library.

*This information isn't necessary at all, but as I said I'll add all info asked from you, thanks for the attention.*

Comment: What happens in OnPropertyChanged method?

Comment: @lomed when `SelectedRound = Rounds?.FirstOrDefault` is called, then on the setter the value is equal to the item returned from the query, when the method is finished, then the setter of `SelectedRound` is called again and the `value` is null

Comment: DId you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on public class Round ?

Comment: @pix the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented on the property `Rounds` that's the `ItemSource` of the ComboBox, the changing is done correctly.

Comment: You don't create a copy unless your team(s) have different rounds and the team parameter actually changes between calls. ToList() just enumerates the collection to a list, it does not make a copy of the instances, so if the team(s) have different rounds you would expect behavior of first the value is set to null (because wpf does not find the SelectedRound in the Rounds collection you set) and then the actual value is set properly, because you state the exact opposite happens, something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: @Clemens I added to the question my `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation

Comment: @JanneMatikainen In the first execution the `SelectedRound` of course is `Null`, only when the method `LoadRounds` is executed then the `SelectedRound` is valorized 'cause there are rounds available to get from the property `team.Rounds`. For the copy with `.ToList` I've tried also with a deep cloning using `NewtonSoft`, same result, it's not a reference problem.

Comment: How do you invoke the LoadRounds method, how is it bound to ui, where does the Team parameter come from and what else is happening in the method that LoadRounds method is invoked.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Check my second update

Comment: Have you tried setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on your combobox?

Comment: @jode, describing what it does is not showing how it is implemented. I am unable to reproduce this with a freshly created wpf app and using your code and filling the missing parts on my own.

Comment: @dymanoid if I set to true, then I'll get the first item of the collection, to false the same problem.

Comment: could you try overriding the Equals Method on the Round class to for instance just compare the Id Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this order is correct?

```
1. [Item Source updated with new Rounds]
2. [SelectedRound updated from the new `Rounds` available]
3. [SelectedRound setter called again with a null value]
```

After the combo box is initially bound I would expect the order to be (swapped the order of #2 and #3)

```
1. [Item Source updated with new Rounds]
2. [SelectedRound setter called again with a null value]
3. [SelectedRound updated from the new `Rounds` available]
```

This behavior follows what I would expect of a combo box.
When you update the `ItemSource` the ComboBox dumps its items and reloads with the new collection. Because the ComboBox is a Selector, it must then check its `SelectedItem`. If its `SelectedItem` is not found in the new collection it updates its `SelectedItem` to be `null`. All of this happens just because of the `OnPropertyChanged();` call in the `Rounds` setter.
(Note: you will only see this behavior after a combo box has been loaded and bound)

Now there are many ways you can go about handling this, but IMO the simplest is merely to change the order of operations:

```
public void LoadRounds(Team team)
{    
     //Fill the source of ComboBox with the rounds of the new team
     var newRounds = team.Rounds.ToList(); //<- Create a copy, so no reference

     //Get the selected round
     SelectedRound = newRounds.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == team.CurrentRound.Id);
     Rounds = newRounds;
}
```